# VBA excel error converting the nvarchar value to int

Tags: sql, vba, error-handling, int

I created a excel VBA code to get data from the server. It worked very well over a year. However, somehow one of the criteria has been changed about "refused name(no name)" customers. Before we used to assign customer number for them automatically, but with the new changes the system does not assign any customer number customer numbers for those customer instead it gives them "R/N" code. Therefore now I have some problem extracting data from server. I tried to apply some of those "by-pass techniques that I found on net but they did not work for me (talking about CAST). 
    case WHEN isnumeric([CustId]) THEN CAST([CustId] AS int) else 0 end

but it did not work. I get this error:"Run-time error ' -2147217913 (80040e07) 
[Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Conversation failed 
when converting the nvarchar value 'R/Nto data type int. "

All I need is disregard those "R/N" in customer id field. Please have a look at my vba code below.
 Thank you in advance
 Baha

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DBFullName, TableName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, intColIndex As Integer
Dim cel As Range
Dim TD As Double
Dim TD2 As Double
Dim qdate As Double
Dim qdate2 As Double
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim custid 'As String+


TD = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)
TD2 = Target.Offset(-4, -2).Value
custid = Range("custid4").Text

Target.Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.Activate
Set TargetRange = Range("custid4").Offset(2, 0)
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

Conn.Open "driver={SQL Server};" & _
"server=XXXX01\RPTDB;database=Reporting_ODS;"

Set RecSet = New Recordset
RecSet.Open "SELECT TOP(1)Baha_PM.Lname +' '+ Baha_PM.Fname FROM Reporting_ODS.TG.Baha_PM Baha_PM " & _
"WHERE Baha_PM.CustId='" & custid & "'", Conn, , , adCmdText
TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset RecSet

RecSet.Close
Set RecSet = Nothing
Conn.Close
' Trip

Set TargetRange = Range("custid4").Offset(14, 0)
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

Conn.Open "driver={SQL Server};" & _
"server=XXXX01\RPTDB;database=Reporting_ODS;"
 Set RecSet = New Recordset

RecSet.Open "SELECT MAX(Baha_PM.Trip_Id)  FROM Reporting_ODS.TG.Baha_PM Baha_PM " & _
"WHERE Baha_PM.CustId='" & custid & "'", Conn, , , adCmdText
TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset RecSet


RecSet.Close
Set RecSet = Nothing
Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

ISNUMERIC is a SQL Server function. What you need is an Excel VBA function to test if the custid is a number. There is a function ISNumber.

Use this code to fix the string values

```
If Not IsNumber(custid) Then
  Custid = "0"
End If
```

Insert this code straight after you assign the custid varible from the range text

Comment: BTW, in your original code you do not seem to retrieve the CustID anywhere. Can you show us the code where you actually trying to select this value?

Comment: yes my friend I got the same error.In the code you can see that "custid=range("custid4").text" that is one of the way that I look up customer name from the database.

Comment: Got it. I fixed the answer

Comment: I like your thinking but before sql statement there is no problem.I mean the problem is not with the input. But I exactly need that kind of statement in the sql statement. but my sql skills sucks I don't know have to state that if the data is not int consider "0". as you said. thanks

Comment: Where are you getting this error exactly? On what line? What is the structure of the table `Reporting_ODS.TG.Baha_PM`?

Comment: hi Cha, after a while we realized that there was a defect in the database:) that was why it did not work. Thank you for the help...